# ASPxGridView - How to make some field editors read-only when editing a row and allow their editing when adding a new row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspxgridview, devexpress-mvc

I followed it here, https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E5116 and applied given example in ASP.NET MVC. The following is my gridview settings sample partial code:

```
settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.Batch;
settings.SettingsEditing.BatchEditSettings.EditMode = GridViewBatchEditMode.Row;
settings.CellEditorInitialize = (s, e) =>
{
    ASPxGridView grid = s as ASPxGridView;
    ASPxEdit editor = (ASPxEdit)e.Editor;
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "columnName1" || e.Column.FieldName == "columnName2")
    {
        e.Editor.ReadOnly = !grid.IsNewRowEditing;
    }
};
```

Now I can't edit both cells while updating existing row data, that seems perfect.

but I can't edit both columns while creating new row using new button.

Note:- it is working when:

```
 settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.Inline;
```

but not working while editing mode is **Batch**.

Comment: How about you assign the editor's visibility as false and in your CellEditorInitialize, check if grid.IsNewRowEditing and toggle the visibility accordingly. It worked for me!

Comment: @GHKarim, sounds good, will try and let you know. Thanks Man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i achieved this with help of DevExpress Support:

Grid settings in partial view like following:

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings=> {
settings.Name = "gridViewPartial";
settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "gridViewPartial" };
settings.SettingsEditing.BatchUpdateRouteValues = new { Controller = "Admin", Action = "gridViewBatchUpdate" };

settings.KeyFieldName = "Id";

settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.Batch;
settings.SettingsEditing.BatchEditSettings.EditMode = GridViewBatchEditMode.Cell;


//to handle edit events on client side
**settings.ClientSideEvents.BatchEditStartEditing = "OnBatchStartEdit";**

settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
settings.CommandColumn.ShowDeleteButton = true;
settings.CommandColumn.ShowNewButtonInHeader = true;


settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "Id";
    column.Caption = "ID";
    column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.SpinEdit;

});
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "Name";
    column.Caption = "Name";

});

}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Grid Normal page in which i am refering partial view:

```
//script to handle edit event
function OnBatchStartEdit(s, e) {
    if ((e.focusedColumn.fieldName == "Id") && (e.visibleIndex > -1)) //cancel example
        e.cancel = true;;
}
```

For further reference 
visit here https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T386483